# Strange output of ColorFunction

Tags: color

In v10.0.2, compare the following two outputs:

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2]] &)]
```

> [image: wrong output]

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2]] &), 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

> [image: right output]

The second output is right, however, in any sense, the first output should have rotational symmetry with respect to z axes at the origin.

Is this a bug or do I make a huge mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is not a bug. It's because the default [`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) puts the arguments of the `ColorFunction` into the range `0` to `1`. By using `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` you suppress this default scaling and get the rings centered at the minimum. With default `ColorFunctionScaling`, you would have to do the following:

```
 Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[Sqrt[(#1 - .5)^2 + (#2 - .5)^2]] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I misundertood `ColorFunctionScaling`  to be the one to rescale function's return value such as f[...] in `Hue[f[...]]` into the range 0 to 1.